# UITableviewCell textLabel not visible in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am using following code to display cell of `UITableView`,

```
static NSString *identifier=@"reusableIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"hi"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12.0];
        [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
        cell.textLabel.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        NSLog(@"textlabel frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame));
        return cell;
```

its working fine in ios 6 , its showing textlabel in ios6 , but in ios7 its not showing textLabel.

Except textLabel everything is working fine in ios7.

And one more thing before writing sizetofit, frame of textLabel was (0,0,0,0)

but after adding `sizetofit` its (0,0,12,15), even though its not showing textLabel.

tableview in ios 7
[image: tableview in ios 7]
tableview in ios 6
[image: tableview in ios 6]

Comment: try this     cell.textLabel.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;

Comment: @CharanGiri tried but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with this one:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    CGAffineTransform rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
    self.tableView.transform = rotateTable;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100,self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier=@"reusableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
     NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"hi"];

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12.0];
    [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
    cell.textLabel.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    NSLog(@"textlabel frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame));

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks but not working , and what do u think which point from your code should solve my problem?

Comment: i have checked it. worked fine. all cells showed 'hi';

Comment: Adding an explanation to what was the problem that you corrected in your code would be convenient.